# Margin setting for PhD Theses on MacTex

Tags: margins, geometry

I am writing my PhD thesis in TexShop for Mac and I am struggling to set my margins to adhere to my submission guidelines. I will be printing it as two-sided and I am currently using book class (although I was wondering if report might be better?). The margins need to be at least 4.0cm on the inside (for binding) and at least 1.5cm at the top, bottom and outside. Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Package geometry for page margin setting.

Comment: Thanks I have the use package geometry:\usepackage{geometry}. Should I just be able to enter the margins that I require?

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm, bindingoffset=1cm, inner=3cm]{geometry}
```

or

```
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm, bindingoffset=1cm, inner=3cm, includeheadfoot]{geometry}
```

if you want headers and footers *not* to be in the margin.